# Running visible .bat from java, and reading the output

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I'm having a little problem and I'm in need of some help.

The issue is simple: I'm trying to run a **.bat** file from a **java program** and then reading the exit code.. but I need to see what the .bat is doing.

The .bat file just execute some external programas and the return a:

```
exit %errorlevel%
```

My java program do the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait "+file);
int result = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("exit = "+result);
```

The problem is that when I use the **"start /wait"** parameters, I CAN see the .bat execution but can not read the output.. it is always 0.

If I call the .bat **without** the "start /wait" I can read the output well!.. but I cannot see the execution of the bat.

I tried reading **getInputStream()** and **getErrorStream()** and it didn't work.

Any help please? What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm returning from the bat incorrectly.. or I'm missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for `cmd`. You are making the batch file execution be completely detached from the process you create. You need this code instead:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \""+file+"\"");
// ...
```

This makes it so that the batch file output is readable from the `Process`'s input stream. Also, it quotes the file name in case it has any spaces.

It is not possible to make the command window visible and still be able to read the output from your java code (at least not without native code) so perhaps you should make your own `JFrame` and put the output there.

Comment: Ohh, ok, thanks for the answer!! I will try to find an alternative solution.. like sending the exitCode to a file and reading it from there.. or maybe saving it in like an Environment Variable?? It's possible? Maybe I will say something stupid.. but if I try to read the ERRORLEVEL directly from the java.. will it work?

Comment: Edited my answer, please read. If you want a native solution I recommend you google it or post a new question.

Comment: No reading errorlevel won't work because `start` detaches the process from the parent process that invoked start. Basically, it returns success immediately, regardless of whether or not the actual program actually finished yet.